# Update Android UI Without Leaking Memory

Tags: android

I have a very simple Android Activity that creates a view and a timer.  The timer task updates the UI with a call to "setTextColor".  When executing, I notice memory being allocated by "java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList", caused by the call to "setTextColor".  Is there a way to avoid this?  My intention is to run this simple timer which monitors memory without modifying the consumed memory.

The Activity is as follows:

```
public class AndroidTestActivity extends Activity
{
    Runnable updateUIRunnable;  // The Runnable object executed on the UI thread.
    long previousHeapFreeSize;  // Heap size last time the timer task executed.
    TextView text;              // Some text do display.

    // The timer task that executes the Runnable on the UI thread that updates the UI.
    class UpdateTimerTask extends TimerTask
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            runOnUiThread(updateUIRunnable);
        }       
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Super.
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create the Runnable that will run on and update the UI.
        updateUIRunnable = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                // Set the text color depending on the change in the free memory.
                long heapFreeSize = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
                if (previousHeapFreeSize != heapFreeSize)
                {
                    text.setTextColor(0xFFFF0000);
                }
                else
                {
                    text.setTextColor(0xFF00FF00);                  
                }
                previousHeapFreeSize = heapFreeSize;
            }           
        };

        // Create a frame layout to hold a text view.
        FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        frameLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        // Create and add the text to the frame layout. 
        text = new TextView(this);
        text.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT);
        text.setText("Text");           
        frameLayout.addView(text);

        // Set the content view to the frame layout.    
        setContentView(frameLayout);

        // Start the update timer.
        UpdateTimerTask timerTask = new UpdateTimerTask();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 500, 500);     
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you shouldn't just use the allocation tracker in ddms and the MAT?

Comment: Because both only passively notify you of leaking memory.  I want something on the screen that changes when a memory leak is detected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in Chronometer class in Android http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html

A lot easier than coding it yourself

Comment: The problem isn't the timer, it's the call to "setTextColor" (question has been edited).

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice post from Romainguy about memory leaks:

[Avoiding memory leaks](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.ar/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)

Comment: Right, I'm familiar with the article but doesn't address this.  This is a very simple example and it's hard for me to believe it can't be done without leaking memory.  Can anyone modify the existing code such that the displayed text remains green, as a result of no change in the allocated memory?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem.  Updating the displayed text color was incurring a 24 byte memory allocation. By adjusting for this, only when the text color is updated, I was able to observe a steady amount of consumed memory.